# Sending values between cards with BotFramework Composer

Tags: botframework

Good morning!

I am starting with BotFramework Composer tool using the template RespondingWithCardsSample and I am having problems testing the send of value from one card to another.

On the one hand, I have edited the AdaptivecardJson card with the following basic code.

````
#adaptivecardjson
- ```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                            "placeholder": "Adults",
                            "choices": [
                                {
                                    "title": "1",
                                    "value": "1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "title": "2",
                                    "value": "2"
                                },
                                {
                                    "title": "3",
                                    "value": "3"
                                },
                                {
                                    "title": "4",
                                    "value": "4"
                                }
                            ],
                            "id": "InputAdultos"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Send"
        }
    ]
}
````

This card simply contains an input text indicating the number of adults, the send button and inflates the following card:

```
#AdaptiveCard
[Activity
    Attachments = @{json(adaptivecardjson())}
]
```

Finally, I created another card which simply writes the number of adults received:

```
# HeroCardAdults(InputAdults)
[HeroCard
text = The number of adults is @{InputAdults}
]
```

But I just didn't understand how it works and it gives me the following error:

*common.lg: Error occurs when evaluating expression bfdactivity-028800 (): Error occurs when evaluating expression HeroCardAdults (): Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: ‘inputadults’ does not match memory scopes: user, conversation, turn, settings, dialog, class, this*

Has it happened to someone else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your template to

```
# HeroCardAdults(InputAdults)
[HeroCard
text = The number of adults is {InputAdults}
]
```

or if you want to use memory scopes, set your value to dialog.InputAdults and use this template

```
# HeroCardAdults
[HeroCard
text = The number of adults is {dialog.InputAdults}
]
```